# Tensorflow: Compilation using SSE and AVX

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

On my virtual Ubuntu machine (MacOS on metal). I have installed the tensorflow as the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv) with mode `Installing with virtualenv`.

With the following set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv
virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

And then for validation:

```
python
import tensorflow as tf   
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')   
sess = tf.Session()
```

But then I receive the following set of warnings, which I am not sure as how to deal with it.

> ```
>  The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>     The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speedup CPU computations.
>     The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speedup CPU computations.
> ```

My machine does not have a NVIDIA card. So the installation for CPU only.

So, question is how to proceed from here and so as to get the code compiled using the AVX and SSE. Or I have to remove this installation and compile it with source(scared to do it).

Comment: Since you're in a virtual environment, you shouldn't need to _remove_ your current install to attempt installing from source.  Also, FWIW, I recently installed the 1.1 branch from source on OS-X (to enable SSE) without any real problems.  Obviously that's different than doing it on Ubuntu, but it's probably still worth a try...